# How to convert datetime format in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas datetime column and I need to convert to required format.

```
0   2017-09-27 07:54:20
1   2017-09-27 08:24:04
2   2017-09-27 09:02:06
3   2017-09-27 09:04:14
4   2017-09-27 09:04:18
```

```
0   2017-09-27T07:54:20
1   2017-09-27T08:24:04
2   2017-09-27T09:02:06
3   2017-09-27T09:04:14
4   2017-09-27T09:04:18
```

I have split the column in to two ,add 'T' value and merged together. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dt.strftime`

```
#df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df.date=df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```